# Making multiple objects move as one object under the same ID in HTML

Tags: html, css, object, animation, keyframe

I'm a beginner and just playing around with HTML after learning about animations. I'm trying to build a rocket ship that "blasts off." The problem is, when I specify id: "fly", only the class:"rockethead" moves. What am I doing wrong and how do I make the "rocket" and it's associated classes move as well?

Additionally, I need all these objects to move together, and end in the same shape they begin in. With my current animation, when these objects "blastoff", they will no longer be in the shape of a rocket at the top (essentially, I just want the top of the "rockethead" to touch 500px, taking the rest of the rocket under it but without falling apart. What can I do to achieve this? Is there a better way I can chain all of these parts together into one object, so I can move it more efficiently?

```css
.rocket {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30em;
}

.rocket::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: -11px;
  right: 50px;
  transform: skewY(-40deg);
}

.rocket::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: -11px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: skewY(40deg);
}

.rockethead {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 100px;
  bottom: 47;
}

#fly {
  animation-name: blastoff;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes blastoff {
  0% {
    bottom: relative;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="fly" class="rockethead"></div>
<div id="fly" class="rocket"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id's should be unique, you should give them the same class.

```
<div class="rockethead fly"></div>
<div class="rocket fly"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I made them all classes and everything _should_ work - but the "rockethead" is still the only thing moving when I also have class="rocket fly"

Comment: That's because you're positioning the .rocket with top: 30em and animating the bottom property. Try to position the .rocket using bottom property instead of top property.

Answer (score 0):

The id of any element must be unique. No two-element can have the same name ID.Use classes to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to that the id should be unique and in order to achieve what you want you have to wrap your divs with a wrapper div we call it as the below:

Html

```
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="rockethead"></div>
      <div class="rocket"></div>
    </div>
```

Css

```
.rocket {
  width: 50px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.rocket::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: -11px;
  right: 50px;
  transform: skewY(-40deg);
}

.rocket::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: -11px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: skewY(40deg);
}

.rockethead {
  height:0;
  width:0;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  position:relative;
}

@keyframes blastoff {
  0% {
    bottom:0;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 75%;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0%;
  left:50%;
  animation: blastoff 2s infinite;
  }
```

Codepen for the above https://codepen.io/ahamdan/pen/jOrqaOy

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I'm new to this but can tell I'll be wrapping objects often in the future.